# Python: TypeError: zip argument #1 must support iteration

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, zip-operator

I'm getting an error when using the **zip(*map(...))** call. Long explanation see below.

> TypeError: zip argument #1 must support iteration

Here's what I got. A dataframe containing cities and their location in longitude and latitude. Now I want to calculate the distance between the cities using the [harversine formular](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula).

Starting point is this Pandas DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame([{'city':"Berlin", 'lat':52.5243700, 'lng':13.4105300},
                   {'city':"Potsdam", 'lat':52.3988600, 'lng':13.0656600},
                   {'city':"Hamburg", 'lat':53.5753200, 'lng':10.0153400}]);
df
```

Then I'm joining the dataframe with itself in order to get pairs of cities:

```
df['tmp'] = 1
df2 = pd.merge(df,df,on='tmp')
df2 = df2[df2.city_x != df2.city_y]
```

Which gives me this:

```
    city_x  lat_x       lng_x       tmp city_y  lat_y       lng_y
1   Berlin  52.52437    13.41053    1   Potsdam 52.39886    13.06566
2   Berlin  52.52437    13.41053    1   Hamburg 53.57532    10.01534
3   Potsdam 52.39886    13.06566    1   Berlin  52.52437    13.41053
5   Potsdam 52.39886    13.06566    1   Hamburg 53.57532    10.01534
6   Hamburg 53.57532    10.01534    1   Berlin  52.52437    13.41053
7   Hamburg 53.57532    10.01534    1   Potsdam 52.39886    13.06566
```

Now let's do the important part. The harversine formular is put into a function:

```
def haversine_distance(lng1: float, lat1: float, lng2: float, lat2: float) -> float:
    """
    Computes the distance in kilometers between two points on a sphere given their longitudes and latitudes 
    based on the Harversine formula. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula
    """
    from math import radians, cos, sin, asin, sqrt
    R = 6371 # Radius of earth in kilometers. Use 3956 for miles

    lng1, lat1, lng2, lat2 = map(radians, [lng1, lat1, lng2, lat2])

    # haversine formula 
    dlng = lng2 - lng1 
    dlat = lat2 - lat1 
    a = sin(dlat/2)**2 + cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) * sin(dlng/2)**2
    c = 2 * asin(sqrt(a)) 
    distance = c * R
    return distance
```

This function should then be called on the joined dataframe:

```
def get_haversine_distance(lng1: pd.Series, lat1: pd.Series, lng2: pd.Series, lat2: pd.Series) -> pd.Series:
    dist = zip(*map(haversine_distance, lng1, lat1, lng2, lat2))
    return dist

# now invoke the method in order to get a new column (series) back
get_haversine_distance(df2['lng_x'], df2['lat_x'], df2['lng_y'], df2['lat_y'])
```

**Problem/Error:** This gives me the following error:

> TypeError: zip argument #1 must support iteration

**Remark:** What I don't get, is why I'm getting the error since this other method (see below) works perfectly fine. Basically the same thing!

```
def lat_lng_to_cartesian(lat: float, lng: float) -> float:
    from math import radians, cos, sin
    R = 6371 # Radius of earth in kilometers. Use 3956 for miles

    lat_, lng_ = map(radians, [lat, lng])

    x = R * cos(lat_) * cos(lng_)
    y = R * cos(lat_) * sin(lng_)
    z = R * sin(lat_)
    return x, y, z

def get_cartesian_coordinates(lat: pd.Series, lng: pd.Series) -> (pd.Series, pd.Series, pd.Series):
    if lat is None or lng is None:
        return
    x, y, z = zip(*map(lat_lng_to_cartesian, lat, lng))
    return x, y, z

get_cartesian_coordinates(df2['lat_x'], df2['lng_x'])
```

Comment: Ok, tried, but didn't work. Also the get_cartesian_coordinates function works without the list-thing.

Comment: I don't think that's how `map` really works. Ideally, you want to supply the `mapped` function with each element of the iterable. What you need to do is `zip` elements of the `pd.Series` and then use `map` with the `haversine_distance` function.

Comment: Something like: `dist = pd.Series(map(lambda x: haversine_distance(*x), zip(lng1, lat1, lng2, lat2)))`.

Comment: PS: why getting a down-vote?

Comment: Seems like someone is downvoting everything. It'd be great if they could let us all know what's wrong with both the question and its answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, to be able to use the `haversine_distance` in the current way you've defined it, you are going to need to `zip` those columns first before `mapping`. In essence, you will need to edit the `get_haversine_distance` function to make sure that it is `zipping` the corresponding rows into tuples before unpacking each tuple into arguments for the `haversine_distance` function. The following is an illustration, using the provided data:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame([{'city':"Berlin", 'lat':52.5243700, 'lng':13.4105300},
                   {'city':"Potsdam", 'lat':52.3988600, 'lng':13.0656600},
                   {'city':"Hamburg", 'lat':53.5753200, 'lng':10.0153400}]);
df

#       city       lat       lng  tmp
# 0   Berlin  52.52437  13.41053    1
# 1  Potsdam  52.39886  13.06566    1
# 2  Hamburg  53.57532  10.01534    1

# Make sure to reset the index after you filter out the unneeded rows
df['tmp'] = 1
df2 = pd.merge(df,df,on='tmp')
df2 = df2[df2.city_x != df2.city_y].reset_index(drop=True)

#     city_x     lat_x     lng_x  tmp   city_y     lat_y     lng_y
# 0   Berlin  52.52437  13.41053    1  Potsdam  52.39886  13.06566
# 1   Berlin  52.52437  13.41053    1  Hamburg  53.57532  10.01534
# 2  Potsdam  52.39886  13.06566    1   Berlin  52.52437  13.41053
# 3  Potsdam  52.39886  13.06566    1  Hamburg  53.57532  10.01534
# 4  Hamburg  53.57532  10.01534    1   Berlin  52.52437  13.41053
# 5  Hamburg  53.57532  10.01534    1  Potsdam  52.39886  13.06566

def get_haversine_distance(lng1: pd.Series, lat1: pd.Series, lng2: pd.Series, lat2: pd.Series) -> pd.Series:
    dist = pd.Series(map(lambda x: haversine_distance(*x), zip(lng1, lat1, lng2, lat2)))
    return dist


def haversine_distance(lng1: float, lat1: float, lng2: float, lat2: float) -> float:
    """
    Computes the distance in kilometers between two points on a sphere given their longitudes and latitudes 
    based on the Harversine formula. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula
    """
    from math import radians, cos, sin, asin, sqrt
    R = 6371 # Radius of earth in kilometers. Use 3956 for miles
    lng1, lat1, lng2, lat2 = map(radians, [lng1, lat1, lng2, lat2])
    # haversine formula
    dlng = lng2 - lng1
    dlat = lat2 - lat1
    a = sin(dlat/2)**2 + cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) * sin(dlng/2)**2
    c = 2 * asin(sqrt(a))
    distance = c * R
    return distance


df2['distance'] = get_haversine_distance(df2['lng_x'], df2['lat_x'], df2['lng_y'], df2['lat_y'])

#     city_x     lat_x     lng_x  tmp   city_y     lat_y     lng_y    distance
# 0   Berlin  52.52437  13.41053    1  Potsdam  52.39886  13.06566   27.215704
# 1   Berlin  52.52437  13.41053    1  Hamburg  53.57532  10.01534  255.223782
# 2  Potsdam  52.39886  13.06566    1   Berlin  52.52437  13.41053   27.215704
# 3  Potsdam  52.39886  13.06566    1  Hamburg  53.57532  10.01534  242.464120
# 4  Hamburg  53.57532  10.01534    1   Berlin  52.52437  13.41053  255.223782
# 5  Hamburg  53.57532  10.01534    1  Potsdam  52.39886  13.06566  242.464120
```

Let me know if this is what you expect the output to look like.

Comment: Perfect. I feel that I'm still not really used to zip and map or even *map.

Comment: very nice, plus1

Answer (score 3):

Your `haversine_distance` function returns a single number, but `zip` wants an iterable, hence it fails with an exception.

`lat_lng_to_cartesian` works because it's returning a 3-tuple, which is iterable.

You could get rid of the exception by returning a 1-tuple:

```
return (distance,)
```

But I don't see the point for doing it here -- you actually don't need to zip at all:

```
def get_haversine_distance(lng1: pd.Series, lat1: pd.Series, lng2: pd.Series, lat2: pd.Series) -> pd.Series:
    dist = map(haversine_distance, lng1, lat1, lng2, lat2)
    return pd.Series(dist)
```

Comment: The latter one works fine. Thanks. My fault of using zip in a wrong way.

Answer (score 1):

As Andrea points out the issue is that haversine_distance returns a number instead of an iterator. That being said, you could also use `apply` to df2:

```
df2.apply(lambda row: haversine_distance(row['lng_x'], row['lat_x'], row['lng_y'], row['lat_y']), axis=1)
```

Comment: True, I had this code before, too. I guess the performance is better, too. But if I add the harversine method to a utils-file, then it would be cool to have the function-syntax with the series arguments as mentioned in my original post.